# Why can't I chown to nobody over nfsv4?

Tags: freebsd, nfs4

Server: FreeBSD 9.2-RC1, ZFS
Client: FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE-p3
Filesystem is exported with "alldirs,maproot=root".

On the client, I can chown a file to any user but nobody.

```
client# touch foo
client# ls -l foo
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  0 Aug 20 11:18 foo
client# chown chris foo
client# ls -l foo
-rw-r--r--  1 chris  staff  0 Aug 20 11:18 foo
client# chown root foo
client# ls -l foo
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  0 Aug 20 11:18 foo
client# chown nobody foo
No name and/or group mapping for uid,gid:(65534,-1)
chown: foo: Operation not permitted
```

nobody exists on both client and server, with UID 65534 in both places. It looks like this is something to do with nfsv4's user mapping (nfsuserd), but I'm not finding good documentation on how that works. I've read hints that nobody is handled specially.

Comment: what are your export options?

Comment: looks like your user nobody has a group without mapping

Comment: @PetterH, Filesystem is exported with "alldirs,maproot=root".

Comment: @tigran, I think gid is -1 because it's not trying to change the group ownership. At any rate, the mapping is the same on both machines: uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nobody) groups=65534(nobody)